# Remove duplicate before group by SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, duplicates

I need remove duplicates in SELECT before count them. I need to count how many test have been done. A patient can't get same value for the same test. I had tried `DISTINCT` but it would be a `GROUP BY(DISTINCT)` instead of `GROUP BY(GROUP BY)`. It is pretty much the same but `DISTINCT` will remove other columns I need in patient_test table. I used a view as a good practice, but I'm not sure that is helping.

TLDR: I want to improve a nested GROUP BY, but I can't find a way.

```
table: patient_test (12 rows)

Patient | Test      | Value
--------------------------------
Laura   | Test A    |  1.3
Laura   | Test B    |  8.9 <-          
Laura   | Test B    |  8.9 <-  
Laura   | Test C    |  8.9           
Charles | Test B    |  8.9           
Charles | Test B    |  4.6           
Charles | Test C    |  5.6           
Maria   | Test A    |  1.2 <--
Maria   | Test A    |  1.2 <--
Maria   | Test B    |  1.2
Maria   | Test B    |  8.9
Maria   | Test C    |  1.2
```

I exclude duplicates this way

```
SELECT * FROM patient_test 
GROUP BY Patient , Test, Value
```

to get:

```
table: patient_test (10 rows)

Patient | Test      | Value
--------------------------------
Laura   | Test A    |  1.3
Laura   | Test B    |  8.9         
Laura   | Test C    |  8.9           
Charles | Test B    |  8.9           
Charles | Test B    |  4.6           
Charles | Test C    |  5.6           
Maria   | Test A    |  1.2  
Maria   | Test B    |  1.2
Maria   | Test B    |  8.9
Maria   | Test C    |  1.2
```

Then I count them this way: (What I want to improve)

```
SELECT TestName, count(*) AS Result FROM 
(SELECT * FROM patient_test 
GROUP BY Patient , Test, Value) AS tempPatient
GROUP BY tempPatient.TestName;
```

I'm using a view, but I think that exclude duplicates and them `GROUP BY` right away could be better.

```
SELECT TestName, count(*) AS Result FROM 
(CustomView) AS tempPatient
GROUP BY tempPatient.TestName;
```

I cannot use this one as a part of the solution, because it will remove other columns I need for other procedures.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Patient,Test,Value
FROM patient_test
```

This is what I need:

```
TestName  | Result
----------------------
Test A    |  2
Test B    |  5
Test C    |  3
```

I think that is not necessary to run  `GROUP BY` twice.  I would like to find a way to exclude duplicates using the examples.
Any help or suggestion would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike other databases MySql allows more than one columns referenced with `DISTINCT` inside `COUNT()`:

```
SELECT Test, COUNT(DISTINCT Patient, Value) AS Result
FROM patient_test 
GROUP BY Test;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=953927b0bf90e52d7dbb3ec76ea1b34e).

Comment: Just to know because I thought of this solution too, shouldn't `Patient`, `Value` columns  be the same data type ?

Comment: @ErgestBasha no, DISTINCT has nothing to do with the data types.

Answer (score 0):

Seems fine what you have done. I would do something very similar:

```
SELECT 
    T.Test,
    COUNT(*) AS Result 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            Patient,
            Test,
            Value
        FROM 
            patient_test
        ) T
GROUP BY
    T.Test
;
```

If you have duplicates in the table, you have to use grouping or distinct to remove them - that is pretty much standard operating procedure in a case like this.

Comment: Thank you, I had considered `DISTINCT` , but It will remove other columns I need from the first SELECT.